# Javascript: firstChild object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious why the firstChild-object returns undefined in the following code? IF I omit  **child = child.nextSibling;**

It works fine if I in the next row calls nextSibling

```
  divs  = $('.post')
  for(ind in divs){
   div = divs[ind];
   var child = div.firstChild;
   child = child.nextSibling; //omitting this causes undefined
   alert (child.innerHTML);
  }
```

html

```
    .....
         <div class="post">
                <h4>
                    HEADER
                </h4>
                <div class="content">
                    <p>
                        text goes here
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>
  ......
```

Comment: that's not how you iterate jQuery collections. use $.each(), or at least a .length-based for loop.

Comment: Did you actually log what `div` is inside the loop? Not sure where you learned to use `for in` with jQuery

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why don't you just use its methods like `.children()` and `.next()`?

Answer (score 1):

There is whitespace in your HTML document between the `<div class="post">` and `<h4>` tags. Accessing the [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) property of `div` returns you the text node containing this whitespace. Text nodes don't have an `innerHTML` property, so you get an `undefined` result.

Accessing the [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property of the text node returns the node after the whitespace, the `<h4>` element.

To directly access the first child that is an element (skipping text nodes), you can use the [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) property instead of `firstChild`.

There is also a problem with the for loop in your code. This will iterate over over all the properties of the JQuery collection, not just the indexes. You should use JQuery's [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method instead.

Iterating the `div` elements using `.each()` and `firstElementChild`:

```
var divs = $('.post');
divs.each(function() {
  var div = this;    
  var child = div.firstElementChild;
  alert(child.innerHTML);
});
```

Using JQuery to select the first element child with the [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector:

```
$('.post>:first-child').each(function() {
  alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Comment: might consider `.children[0]` for wider compat than `.firstElementChild` -$-0.02...

Comment: @dandavis compatibility for `firstElementChild` is only really an issue if you've got to support IE < 9. There is browser compatibility information and a polyfill to support old browsers on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild). Note also that `children` returns comment nodes in IE < 9.

Comment: i was thinking about IE8, but it all begs the question of why use dom  methods at all if jQuery is right there...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing something wrong: using `for(key in jQueryObject) {` for iterating through a jQuery collection.
The loop doesn't just iterate through the selected elements in the collection. It iterates through all the object properties, i.e. the `divs[ind]` can be one of the jQuery methods or properties and not just a DOM element.

Since the jQuery object is an array-like object, it has numeric properties that refer to selected elements. But for other properties and methods the loop will simply fail.

Assuming you have just one `.post` element:

In the first iteration the `ind` is 0 and it refers to the first selected element in set.

In the second iteration the `ind` is `length`. `divs[ind]` returns the `length` of the collection and not a DOM element. This is also the case for other jQuery properties and methods and it's other inherited properties.

Also since order of object properties is undefined you may get different results on different browsers.

---

For iterating through the jQuery collections use the `.each` method.